# MarkLogic multi-master replication

Tags: marklogic, multi-master-replication

We are working with a Global Editorial Team Geographically distributed and MarkLogic has been chosen as underlying data store.

To support 0 down time and quick response time, we want to setup distributed data store with multi-master replication. We want to know whether MarkLogic provides out of the box or through any other mechanism provision for such multi-master replication configuration?

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic has various features for High-Availability, and Disaster Recovery out of the box. Most of them are not meant for multi-master replication. Flexible Replication on the other hand, could be configured such that it would allow multi-master replication.

The framework comes out of the box, but you will have to play around with its configuration to see how to best make this work. You need to be careful to not cause endless loops, and apply smart filtering to prevent that.

The Flexible Replication Guide is a good starting point to learn more about it:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/flexrep/rep_intro

HTH!